# Action Get doesn't work. Cgi, Lazarus IDE

Tags: mysql, get, action, freepascal, lazarus

I have this simple code:

```
procedure TFPWebModule1.DataModuleRequest(Sender: TObject; ARequest: TRequest; 
AResponse: TResponse; var Handled: Boolean);`
var  CityName, Testo, Valore: String;
  begin
  Testo := '';
    Conn := TSQLConnector.Create(nil);
    with Conn do begin
      ConnectorType := 'mysql 5.7';
      HostName := 'localhost';
      DatabaseName := 'world';
      UserName := 'root';
      Password := 'password';
      Transaction := TSQLTransaction.Create(Conn);
    end;

  CityName := ARequest.QueryFields.Values['CityName'];
  if CityName = emptyStr then
    with AResponse.Contents do
    begin
      Add('<form action="' + ARequest.URI + '" method="GET"');
      Add('<label for="CityName"> Which city do you want to show?: </label>');
      Add('<input type="text" name="CityName" id="CityName" />');
      Add('<input type="submit" value="Send" />');
      Add('</form>');
    end
  else
    Query := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
    Query.DataBase := Conn;
    Query.SQL.Text := 'select * from city where Name = "' + CityName + '"';
    Query.Open;
      for F in Query.Fields do begin
        Testo := Testo +' '+ F.FieldName +':';
        if F.IsNull then Testo := Testo //non fa niente
        else Valore := F.value;
        Testo := Testo +' '+ Valore + ', ';
      end;
      Testo := Testo + '<br></br>';
      Query.Next;
    Query.Close;
    Query.Free;
    Conn.Free;
    AResponse.Content := 'Risultato: ' +Testo;
    Handled := true;
    end;

initialization
  RegisterHTTPModule('TFPWebModule1', TFPWebModule1);
end.
```

I tried literally everything but doesn't work. The result that I obtain when I go to localhost/cgi-bin/cgiproject1.exe is an empty query:
Result: ID: , Name: , CountryCode: , District: , Population: ,
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

First, i miss:  `Conn.cennected:=true;`
Second  there is no Contenttype for AResponse. may there schould be something like: `AResponse.ContentType := 'text/html;charset=utf-8';`
Last Idea: May you cold change  `AResponse.Content := 'Risultato: ' +Testo;` --> `AResponse.Contents.add('Risultato: ' +Testo);`